# How to make $sce.trustAsHtml() not reject data attributes?

Tags: html, angularjs, custom-data-attribute

Apparently, `$sce.trustAsHtml()` rejects the HTML `data-*` attributes that are present in the HTML string to be used. How can I make Angular not reject `data-*` attributes?

Comment: In the meantime I've discovered `$sceProvider.enabled(false)` and having no better options, I started to use it. I think that `data-*` attributes shouldn't be rejected by `$sce.trustAsHtml()`.

Comment: sounds like you think you found a bug; you probably should file it in their issue tracker https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues

Comment: Reported at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11034